# C++ function that returns a pointer to a member function

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, consteval

the following works as expected:

```cpp
template<typename... Types>
auto countNumberOfTypes() { return sizeof...(Types); }

template<typename... Types>
consteval auto functionReturnsFunction() { return countNumberOfTypes<Types...> };

functionReturnsFunction<int, const double>()() == 2;
```

but the following does not even compile:

```cpp
struct Test
{
    template<typename... Types>
    auto countNumberOfTypes() { return sizeof...(Types); }
};

template<typename... Types>
consteval auto functionReturnsFunction2() { return &Test::countNumberOfTypes<Types...>; }

// functionReturnsFunction2<int, const double>()() == 2;
```

```
error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘&Test::countNumberOfTypes (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* &Test::countNumberOfTypes) (...)’
   29 |     if (functionReturnsFunction2<int, const double>()() == 2)
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

...any suggestions?

Comment: Please show a [mre] that produces your error.  Your "does not even compile" code  [compiles and doesn't generate anything](https://godbolt.org/z/6cMn4aenr)

Comment: @DrewDormann: The error message matches the commented-out line.

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a non-static member function, which has to be called on an object.  Either make the function static, or plan to have an instance of the class when calling it.

Comment: In order to call a non-static member function of class `Test`, you need an object of type `Test`. There is no such object in `functionReturnsFunction2<int, const double>()()`. How do you expect this to work?

Comment: Should be `(Test{}.*functionReturnsFunction2<int, const double>())() == 2`.

Comment: Does changing it to "return &Test::template countNumberOfTypes<Types...>;" make any difference?

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, that works for me. Thank you! The error message was too cryptic to me to solve it and syntax is also quite ugly, but it works. Please make it as answer I will mark it as solved.

Comment: @n. m. could be an AII also tried `template<typename... Types>
consteval auto functionReturnsFunction2(const Test& test) { return &test.countNumberOfTypes<Types...>; }` with `Test test{}; functionReturnsFunction2<int, const double>(test)() == 2;` but I just obtained different error message.

Comment: Error message seemed quite clear. ` must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘&Test::countNumberOfTypes (...)’` - ` - you are trying to call a pointer-to-member function. ` `e.g. ‘(... ->* &Test::countNumberOfTypes) (...)’` it's telling you what you should have written. `(something->*&Test::countNumberOfTypes)(something)` - how would you recommend improving the error message?

Comment: @Raymond Chen I appologise, I am not an expert. At least the syntax `->*&` is quite weird. But unfortunatelly I sill do not follow: what should be that `something` in `(something->*&Test::countNumberOfTypes)(something)` ? a `Test` object? in function `consteval auto functionReturnsFunction2(const Test& test) { return test->*&countNumberOfTypes<Types...>(test); }` ? That syntax is just so weird that I am completely lost...

Comment: The error message assumes that you know that a pointer to a member function requires an object to apply it to. (Otherwise, which object's countNumberOfTypes are you calling?) The C++ syntax for applying pointers to member functions is quite weird, but seeing as you went out of your way to create a pointer to a member function (it's hard to type `&Test::countNumberOfTypes<Types...>` by mistake!) there is a presumption that you had some basic knowledge of the subject in order to get this far. The compiler is not trying to teach you C++; it's just trying to tell you the correct syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pointer to member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions) requires special syntax with `.*` or `->*` to be used (and an object).

`(Test{}.*functionReturnsFunction2<int, const double>())() == 2)`

Alternatively, you might use [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) which might have more regular syntax

`(std::invoke(functionReturnsFunction2<int, const double>(), Test{}) == 2)`